# How can I open a website in my web browser using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to enter a login, username and then click the button login in Instagram. Here is my code (Problem is below):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from secrets import pw

class InstaBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input')\
            .send_keys(username)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\'password\']")\
            .send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type=\'submit\']")\
            .click()
        sleep(4)

InstaBot('myusername', 'mypassword')
```

However, every time I run it, this happens:[image]

I have no idea why, but it writes my username, goes to the password, enters a couple of digits of the password, and then returns to the username and places the rest of the password there. I am clueless on as of why this is happening.

Comment: Try Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: Do you have a default browser?, if not try to put one.

Comment: @formicaman if he just wants to open a website, then there's no point on using Selenium, which ends up being overkill. `webbrowser.open` should work if he haves a default browser. Otherwise, he could use `webbrowser.get` first to [get a controller for a specific browser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get)

Comment: I now have another problem... I'm trying to input a username and password using selenium, can you guys help me? I can update the question

Comment: @yyyyyyyan and formican

Comment: @NicolasFuchs why aren't you selecting the username field by the name as well ? ```"//input[@name=\'username\']"```. Can you try that and let me know what happens

Comment: Hey @OmarNasr, I tried that, I just left it like that because I was testing if they were different. I still have the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
    sleep(2)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input')\
        .send_keys(username)
    sleep(3)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\'password\']")\
        .send_keys(password)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type=\'submit\']")\
        .click()
    sleep(5)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ']").click()
    sleep(4)
```

Comment: Hey! Can you please give me a simple explanation of what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you add this line:                                               self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ']").click()

Comment: Can you probably use Firefox?

Comment: Hey! It didn't work... But I created a loop to go over each character. but now I have another issue. It doesn't click the final log in button

Comment: Can you use another browser?

Comment: I saw what happened... It gave me this message: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

Comment: Can you make more sleep(), probably sleep(10)